# Can we use apoc.ml.openai.embediing with Neo$j desktop?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, azure-openai, openaiembeddings

I want to query neo4j database and get the results converted to natural language using LLM?
Can it be done in neo4j desktop. I have installed APOC plugin ,but I  don't see any apoc.ml procedure in it.

Prompt example:
`#Are there any news regarding return to office policies? CALL apoc.ml.openai.embedding(["Are there any news regarding return to office policies?"],  "{openai_api_key}") YIELD embedding MATCH (c:Chunk) WITH c, gds.similarity.cosine(c.embedding, embedding) AS score ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3 RETURN c.text, score`

I am getting this error when i try using the above query in neo4j desktop:
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound
There is no procedure with the name `apoc.ml.openai.embedding` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of APOC, APOC Core and APOC Extended. APOC Core is officially supported by Neo4j and is available in Aura (the cloud hosted version of Neo4j), Extended is not. The embedding methods are, however, only available in APOC Extended, so one reason could be that you installed APOC Core.

But in version 5.15.0 of Neo4j you no longer need APOC to do embeddings, there are officially supported versions of the embedding procedures/functions with this version that are also available in Aura (or will be very soon).

If you host your own database you need to install a package called neo4j-genai-plugin-5.XX.0.jar (copy it from the products folder to plugins and restart Neo4j). In Aura they are available by default.

The embedding methods are now called:

```
genai.vector.encode
genai.vector.encodeBatch
```

You use them like this (assuming you use OpenAI. It also support VertexAI and AWS Bedrock):

```
WITH genai.vector.encode($phrase, "OpenAI", {token: $apiKey}) AS embedding
```

where $phrase is a single string to embed

or

```
CALL genai.vector.encodeBatch([$phrase1, $phrase2], "OpenAI", {token: $apiKey}) yield index, resource, vector
```

if you have multiple phrases that you want to batch embed

So with your example it would be

```
WITH genai.vector.encode("Are there any news regarding return to office policies?", "OpenAI", {token: "{openai_api_key}"}) AS embedding
MATCH (c:Chunk) WITH c, gds.similarity.cosine(c.embedding, embedding) AS score ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3 RETURN c.text, score
```

Comment: Hi, is the neo4j-genai-plugin-5.XX.0.jar plugin available to download anywhere yet?

Comment: It is part of the 5.17 release of Neo4j and you will need to have that version. If you do have it you just need to copy that file from the products folder to the plugins folder to install it.